# Empty payload after POSTing a file with FormData and Axios

Tags: javascript, axios, multipartform-data

I'm trying to send an image file to an API from a JavaScript using Axios but viewing the request in the console shows the payload as largely empty.

This is what I'm using to send the request

```js
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('image', e.files[0], 'logo.png');

axios.request({
  url: '/upload',
  method: 'post',
  data: formData,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
  }
})
```

The request is being sent, however, the payload for the request is showing only as this

```sh
------WebKitFormBoundaryQums9sVMBwuMo7hO
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="logo.png"
Content-Type: image/png


------WebKitFormBoundaryQums9sVMBwuMo7hO--
```

`e.files[0]` is a valid `File` object and I'm able to call `text()` and `slice()` on it and see the content. I've tried various image files and it's always the same.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? The same problem is driving me crazy for real.